# 1979 firebird custom rack and pinion design

Tags: steering, automotive-design, custom, rack-and-pinion

I am attempting to convert my firebird to a rack and pinion steering system, so I can introduce later modifications.

https://www.unisteer.com/products/1975-81-firebird-trans-am-power-rack-and-pinion-kit

Has a kit, but it is not like a typical rack and pinion system as you will see. The axles do not come straight out of the rack and instead come from the top. I suppose the Pinion Gear is just customized to allow for the top piece to move. I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to do this, but I do know that I have another idea.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/faR17.png]

Since the motion stays linear past the pinion, I do not have to change anything like that, but instead just have the inner tie rods (what come out of the rack) make a 90 degrees turn and another 90 degrees turn until it reaches the tie rod end so it can thread on.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rg2I.png]

It seems a bit more complicated than doing something like this though, where I can just come straight up into the tie rod end when it gets there. This would make it a lot easier since I could just create some aluminum for the tie rod pieces and buy a rack and pinion that comes from another car with the same amount of turn (6.75 inches in a 79 firebird). Theoretically, does this induce any more stress on the pieces that come out of the rack as opposed to the straight design that is sold? Is there any reason this would not work? Are there any flaws? Assuming that there is no complications regarding interference with the frame or anything else on the car.